# Spring LDAP reference: No PersonRepo interface

Tags: java, spring, ldap

This might be a really dumb question, but I'm trying to follow the Spring LDAP guide: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/

However, most of the classes they define implement an interface named "PersonRepo". However, this interface doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer `PersonDao` and `PersonDaoImpl` at [spring-ldap samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples/plain/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/samples/plain/dao). Code for `PersonRepo` is not there in guide but it is same as `PersonDao` interface.